# How to play Facebook and Youtube videos in android?

Tags: android, facebook, video, youtube, vimeo

How do I play Facebook, YouTube and Vimeo videos in my application? I want to play a video by streaming it directly from servers without downloading. I don't want to use default intent. How can I do this?

Comment: Show which parts of your code are failing otherwise we can't help you fix it... If you haven't started, then use Google for finding tools that can extract direct links from such video sites. Asking for tools here is [**`off-topic`**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We answer **technical** / **programming** questions involving "help me with my code issue". A couple of lines of text does not = a real **programming question**. Use the [**`Edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41479061/edit) link when ready to add more useful details (code, error logs, etc)...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [JieCaoVideoPlayer](https://github.com/lipangit/JieCaoVideoPlayer) library provide so many option to play videos

Comment: Does this parse Facebook, YouTube and Vimeo links to get the direct video link (mp4 etc)? I think Asker needs to **extract** the video file web link so as to put directly into their media player code (without using a saved file on disk).

Comment: I think it will not directly parse the links. I have not tried.

Comment: I looked also and don't think it will. Might still be useful Answer to someone so will upvote.

Comment: Is there any to auto start of the video ?